# Getting the last few rows of a large table with query that is using JOINs

Tags: mariadb, join

I'd like to get the last (or last few) rows of a table (named CONTENT) containing more than 10M rows. The query contains joins on 2 other tables and it is extremely slow. These are the table definitions and my query:

```
CREATE TABLE `USER` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `GUID` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `CONTENT` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `guid_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `guid` (`guid_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),

  CONSTRAINT `CONTENT_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`guid_id`) REFERENCES `GUID` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CONTENT_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `USER` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
`CONTENT`.`id`,
`GUID`.`value` AS `guid_value`, 
`USER`.`value` AS `user_value` 
FROM `CONTENT`, `USER`, `GUID` 
WHERE `CONTENT`.`user_id` = `USER`.`id` 
AND `CONTENT`.`guid_id` = `GUID`.`id` 
ORDER BY `CONTENT`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
  # even without ORDER BY the query is slow as seen by explain command
```

These are the results of explain command copied as INSERT:

```
+------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows  | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | GUID    | index  | PRIMARY       | value   | 37      | NULL                        | 16329 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | CONTENT | ref    | guid,user_id  | guid    | 5       | MANAGER.GUID.id             | 293   | Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | USER    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | MANAGER.CONTENT.user_id     | 1     |                                              |
+------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query is unusable so I am splitting it in 2 queries. First, I retrieve the CONTENT.id of interest and second, I plug in an additional `WHERE CONTENT.id = x` clause in the SELECT statement. It seems that in original query MariaDB optimizer does not understand that I only need 1 row, so it makes the cartesian product with every row in the GUID table. Is splitting the query in 2 subqueries the way to go? Can someone comfirm that cartesian product operation is indeed the operation that is causing problems? (first row of explain command results)

EXPLAIN of Ricks query:

```
+------+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys        | key               | key_len | ref                         | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                        | 2       |             |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | CONTENT    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,guid,user_id | PRIMARY           | 4       | c.id                        | 1       | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | USER       | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY           | 4       | MANAGER.CONTENT.user_id     | 1       |             |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | GUID       | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY           | 4       | MANAGER.CONTENT.guid_id     | 1       |             |
|    2 | DERIVED     | CONTENT    | index  | NULL                 | timestamp         | 6       | NULL                        | 9474301 | Using index |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: You don't have a cartesian product, as there are join conditions between all three tables. That syntax of implicit joins using `,` is *highly discouraged* though, as it is easy to mess up and confusing to read. It seems you need to filter `CONTENT` first to 10 rows, then join to the other tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see how fast this runs and what it's Explain says:

```
SELECT  content.`id`, `GUID`.`value` AS `guid_value`, `USER`.`value` AS `user_value`
    FROM  ( SELECT id FROM content ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ) as c
    JOIN content  ON content.id = c.id
    JOIN `USER`  ON user.id = content.user_id
    JOIN `GUID`  ON guid.id = content.guid_id
```

Comment: It's instant. I attached the explain results. In the original query, does mariadb use index to read the full GUID table, because the optimizer does not know it only needs to look for 1 guid? The last row of the newly executed query hints that it will access almost 10M rows (it doesn't).  Can you add a text explanation of the steps that two execution plan will take?